two 2560x1440 monitors, but one of them only shows 3840x2160 in display settings
Basically as the title says, i have two monitors connected to my laptop via a single USB-C to 2x HDMI output.
In the display settings page, one of the monitors is showing correctly at 2560x1440 59.95Hz, but the other only seems to have 3840x2160 at 30Hz or 1080p or lower at 60-144Hz, depending on the other drop down.
The monitor itself is a 2560x1440 and its a gaming monitor at 144Hz.
I can't seem to change it?
The laptop is intel and it has a GTX 1050 Mobile GPU which is capable of outputting the resolution and frames but why cant i see that in the drop down?
Can i force the resolution?
I've already tried various drivers.
lots of forums are recommending that i change my xorg.conf file but i dont seem to have that, and i wouldnt know what to put in there if i did.
any help is really appreciated!

Is there any way to connect the two monitors to 2x HDMI output with two USB-C cables instead of one USB-C cable?

Could you put a screenshot of the default display screen config window? Might help break the text.
